# Changes in csproj file after framework upgrade

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, .net-4.0

As part of framework upgrade of a project ,I went to the properties of the project file and changed the framework to 4.8 from 4.7.
I noticed the following changes.

1. **Addition of Import statement (line 2 in below snapshot)**
   [image]
2. **Addition of following lines under PropertyGroup section.**

[image]

3. **Addition of following line**
   [image]
4. **And the following line changed Condition="false" got added**

[image]

Why is there so many changes after upgrading to 4.8, what kind of challenges I should be expecting if this code moves to prod?

Comment: I would assume these are just updating the project file to be up to date with the latest version of the format. I would not expect anything to change, but it might limit your ability to downgrade visual studio. As with any change, you should test it before moving it to prod.

Comment: Develop projects using the new framework. You need to test the code before moving to prod. Check for compatible, commonly used features.